# Using Isolate scope in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it possible use isolate scope for marked Controllers?

I don't want that html code inner `ng-controller=""` looks for parent $scope values, just want if current Controller scope contains some values - show them, if doesnt not to show.

Is it possible add it without use directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm [reading of the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController), `ng-controller="Foo as vm"` will do what you want.  Instead of it being bound to `$scope` and injecting it into your controller [automatically], you instead would create an isolated scope and refer to it as `this`.